# How to get aggregate volume usage in bytes of my MySQL DB's

Tags: mysql

How can I get the aggregate volume usage for all of my MySQL DB's on my server?  We have 55 DB's and I am wondering if there is a nice, easy way to get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`du -hcs /var/lib/mysql` for a summary of size on disk for everything

`du -hcs /var/lib/mysql/*` this is good for myISAM engine schemas for innoDB the id_data file indicates size on disk for all innoDB files.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most effective ways is to look at the raw file size..
It takes into account your indexs and data..

Which in fact is a good idea ( seeming that your index's need to be read, and hopefully all fit into memory )

du -h /var/lib/mysql/**then your dbs**

Are you running on myisam or innodb??